# How to count the number of files in a directory using Python

Tags: python, count, glob, fnmatch

How do I count only the *files* in a directory? This counts the directory itself as a file:

```
len(glob.glob('*'))
```

Comment: To leave out directories, you can do '*.fileextension' for whatever file extension you are looking for.

Answer (score 416, accepted):

`os.listdir()` will be slightly more efficient than using `glob.glob`.  To test if a filename is an ordinary file (and not a directory or other entity), use `os.path.isfile()`:

```
import os, os.path

# simple version for working with CWD
print len([name for name in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(name)])

# path joining version for other paths
DIR = '/tmp'
print len([name for name in os.listdir(DIR) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(DIR, name))])
```

Comment: Remember to add the `folder_path` inside `os.path.filename(name)` if you're not on the cwd.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893542/why-do-os-path-isfile-return-false

Comment: This doesn't count the file inside nested folders.

Comment: For recursively counting files nested inside directories, you might be better off with the os.walk() solution.

Comment: What is the benefit of using `os.path.join(DIR, name)` over `DIR + '/' + name`? The latter is shorter and, IMO, more clear than the former. Is there perhaps some OS:es on which the latter would fail?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye That's exactly the reason.

Comment: Doing this on a directory with a huge number of files is slow. Is there a way of getting the count in any other way?

Comment: If you need to search for a specific filename, then you can use `'your_filename' in name` like this: `print len([name for name in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(name) and 'your_filename' in name])`

Comment: @HelloGoodbye if prettifying bugs you too much - `pathlib`'s (Pure)Path actually has `/` **operator** which does the same OS-aware stuff - `p / 'some' / 'dir'` https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#operators

Comment: Is this a disk intensive operation to run on unix? I am trying to create a directory serving API and for the UI, I wanna show count of subfolders/files but dont want to wear out the disk too much.

Comment: For those who uses python3, print(len(os.listdir('DIRECTORY_PATH')))

Comment: @DanielStutzbach would you mind updating this answer with Brady Huang 's suggestion ? Edit's queue seems to be full

Answer (score 183):

```
import os

_, _, files = next(os.walk("/usr/lib"))
file_count = len(files)
```

Comment: This isn't recursive

Comment: The OP didn't ask for it to be recursive

Comment: does os.walk no print it in sorted order?

Comment: Fails if folder is empty with StopIteration

Answer (score 86):

For all kind of files, subdirectories included (Python 2):

```
import os

lst = os.listdir(directory) # your directory path
number_files = len(lst)
print number_files
```

**Only files** (avoiding subdirectories):

```
import os

onlyfiles = next(os.walk(directory))[2] #directory is your directory path as string
print len(onlyfiles)
```

Comment: This isn't recursive

Comment: The editing queue is full so...
Please, do not use the builtins (list, dir) as a variable name or a placeholder!

Comment: @NickVeld FTFY...

Comment: Fails if folder is empty with StopIteration

Answer (score 53):

This is where fnmatch comes very handy:

```
import fnmatch

print len(fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(dirpath), '*.txt'))
```

More details: http://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html

Comment: This is much faster (about half the time with my testing on a directory with 10,000 files) if you know the pattern you're looking for, rather then testing each file with `os.path.isfile()` as the accepted answer does. Also significantly faster than `glob.glob()`.

Answer (score 35):

If you want to count all files in the directory - including files in subdirectories, the most pythonic way is:

```
import os

file_count = sum(len(files) for _, _, files in os.walk(r'C:\Dropbox'))
print(file_count)
```

We use sum that is faster than explicitly adding the file counts (timings pending)

Comment: Hi, I was trying to understand this code (the code works perfect), I know we can use `_` in a `for` loop. `os.walk` also I know. But not sure what's going on with underscores inside the `sum` function, could you please elaborate. Thanks!

Comment: Unsderscore is just a variable name @Ejaz, by convention used when we ignore the variable - that's what we do here - we call walk and only count the number of files in each directory, ignoring the root and dirs walk return values

Comment: This is completely recursive and probably the best answer here.

Comment: This should be the most appropriate answer, to also count the files in any subfolders..

Answer (score 27):

An answer with pathlib and without loading the whole list to memory:

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('.')

print(sum(1 for _ in path.glob('*')))  # Files and folders, not recursive
print(sum(1 for _ in path.rglob('*')))  # Files and folders, recursive

print(sum(1 for x in path.glob('*') if x.is_file()))  # Only files, not recursive
print(sum(1 for x in path.rglob('*') if x.is_file()))  # Only files, recursive
```

Comment: Best answer by far!

Comment: or just `sum(1 for _ in path.iterdir())` or `sum(1 for _, x in enumerate(path.iterdir()) if x.is_file())`. Not recursive.

Comment: Instead of `path.glob('**/*')` use `path.rglob('*')`, for recursive versions.

Comment: @MaximilianWolf Also an option, but it [may have different behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75307999/2604492), so I used glob to have the same behavior for both recursive and non-recursive variants.

Answer (score 25):

Short and simple

```
import os
directory_path = '/home/xyz/'
No_of_files = len(os.listdir(directory_path))
```

Comment: Also, no need of directory path if the python file is in the same directory.

Comment: Importantly, this works well in Python 3

Comment: This solution counts also directories, not only files as it was indicated in question.

Answer (score 20):

I am surprised that nobody mentioned `os.scandir`:

```
def count_files(dir):
    return len([1 for x in list(os.scandir(dir)) if x.is_file()])
```

Comment: Works great with Python 3.6!

Answer (score 13):

```
def directory(path,extension):
  list_dir = []
  list_dir = os.listdir(path)
  count = 0
  for file in list_dir:
    if file.endswith(extension): # eg: '.txt'
      count += 1
  return count
```

Answer (score 13):

```
import os
print len(os.listdir(os.getcwd()))
```

Comment: This might be useful sometimes but it includes subdirectories in the count also

Answer (score 10):

This uses `os.listdir` and works for any directory:

```
import os
directory = 'mydirpath'

number_of_files = len([item for item in os.listdir(directory) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(directory, item))])
```

this can be simplified with a generator and made a little bit faster with:

```
import os
isfile = os.path.isfile
join = os.path.join

directory = 'mydirpath'
number_of_files = sum(1 for item in os.listdir(directory) if isfile(join(directory, item)))
```

Answer (score 9):

While I agree with the answer provided by @DanielStutzbach: `os.listdir()` will be slightly more efficient than using `glob.glob`.

However, an extra precision, if you do want to count the number of specific files in folder, you want to use `len(glob.glob())`. For instance if you were to count all the pdfs in a folder you want to use:

```
pdfCounter = len(glob.glob1(myPath,"*.pdf"))
```

Answer (score 7):

This is an easy solution that counts the number of files in a directory containing sub-folders. It may come in handy:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

def count_files(rootdir):
    '''counts the number of files in each subfolder in a directory'''
    for path in pathlib.Path(rootdir).iterdir():
        if path.is_dir():
            print("There are " + str(len([name for name in os.listdir(path) \
            if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, name))])) + " files in " + \
            str(path.name))
            
 
count_files(data_dir) # data_dir is the directory you want files counted.
```

You should get an output similar to this (with the placeholders changed, of course):

```
There are {number of files} files in {name of sub-folder1}
There are {number of files} files in {name of sub-folder2}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
def count_em(valid_path):
   x = 0
   for root, dirs, files in os.walk(valid_path):
       for f in files:
            x = x+1
print "There are", x, "files in this directory."
return x
```

Taked from [this post](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/45188-count-files-directory)

Comment: 1. `files` is a list. 2. OP is not looking for recursive count

Answer (score 6):

one liner and recursive:

```
def count_files(path):
    return sum([len(files) for _, _, files in os.walk(path)])

count_files('path/to/dir')
```

Answer (score 5):

```
import os

def count_files(in_directory):
    joiner= (in_directory + os.path.sep).__add__
    return sum(
        os.path.isfile(filename)
        for filename
        in map(joiner, os.listdir(in_directory))
    )

>>> count_files("/usr/lib")
1797
>>> len(os.listdir("/usr/lib"))
2049
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple one-line command that I found useful:

```
print int(os.popen("ls | wc -l").read())
```

Comment: Parsing the output of `ls` is generally frowned upon (it can frequently cause issues), though this is not a bad "quick-and-dirty" method at the shell. You should use `ls -1`, though, so it guarantees one line per file.

Answer (score 4):

Luke's code reformat.

```
import os

print len(os.walk('/usr/lib').next()[2])
```

Comment: Gives me `AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'next'` in Python 3.11

Answer (score 2):

I used `glob.iglob` for a directory structure similar to

```
data
└───train
│   └───subfolder1
│   |   │   file111.png
│   |   │   file112.png
│   |   │   ...
│   |
│   └───subfolder2
│       │   file121.png
│       │   file122.png
│       │   ...
└───test
    │   file221.png
    │   file222.png
```

Both of the following options return 4 (as expected, *i.e. does not count the subfolders themselves*)

- `len(list(glob.iglob("data/train/*/*.png", recursive=True)))`
- `sum(1 for i in glob.iglob("data/train/*/*.png"))`

Answer (score 2):

It is simple:

```
print(len([iq for iq in os.scandir('PATH')]))
```

it simply counts number of files in directory , i have used list comprehension technique to iterate through specific directory returning all files in return . "len(returned list)" returns number of files.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The quality of this answer can be improved by adding an explanation: [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Thankyou Elletlar , i have edited my answer , i will make sure to respond in more comprehensive manner :D

Answer (score 1):

```
import os

total_con=os.listdir('<directory path>')

files=[]

for f_n in total_con:
   if os.path.isfile(f_n):
     files.append(f_n)


print len(files)
```

Comment: The OP asked for the number of **files**, this lists directories as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you'll be using the standard shell of the operating system, you can get the result much faster rather than using pure pythonic way.

Example for Windows:

```
import os
import subprocess

def get_num_files(path):
    cmd = 'DIR \"%s\" /A-D /B /S | FIND /C /V ""' % path
    return int(subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True))
```

Comment: But it won't be as portable.

Answer (score 1):

I found another answer which may be correct as accepted answer.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(input_path):    
for name in files:
    if os.path.splitext(name)[1] == '.TXT' or os.path.splitext(name)[1] == '.txt':
        datafiles.append(os.path.join(root,name)) 


print len(files)
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple utility function I wrote that makes use of `os.scandir()` instead of `os.listdir()`.

```py
import os 

def count_files_in_dir(path: str) -> int:
    file_entries = [entry for entry in os.scandir(path) if entry.is_file()]

    return len(file_entries)
```

The main benefit is that, the need for `os.path.is_file()` is eliminated and replaced with `os.DirEntry` instance's `is_file()` which also removes the need for `os.path.join(DIR, file_name)` as shown in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

i did this and this returned the number of files in the folder(Attack_Data)...this works fine.

```
import os
def fcount(path):
    #Counts the number of files in a directory
    count = 0
    for f in os.listdir(path):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, f)):
            count += 1

    return count
path = r"C:\Users\EE EKORO\Desktop\Attack_Data" #Read files in folder
print (fcount(path))
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler one:

```
import os
number_of_files = len(os.listdir(directory))
print(number_of_files)
```

Comment: This solution counts also directories, not only files as it was indicated in question.

Answer (score 0):

I find that sometimes I don't know if I will receive filenames or the path to the file. So I printed the os walk solution output:

```
def count_number_of_raw_data_point_files(path: Union[str, Path], with_file_prefix: str) -> int:
    import os
    path: Path = force_expanduser(path)

    _, _, files = next(os.walk(path))
    # file_count = len(files)
    filename: str
    count: int = 0
    for filename in files:
        print(f'-->{filename=}')  # e.g. print -->filename='data_point_99.json'
        if with_file_prefix in filename:
            count += 1
    return count
```

out:

```
-->filename='data_point_780.json'
-->filename='data_point_781.json'
-->filename='data_point_782.json'
-->filename='data_point_783.json'
-->filename='data_point_784.json'
-->filename='data_point_785.json'
-->filename='data_point_786.json'
-->filename='data_point_787.json'
-->filename='data_point_788.json'
-->filename='data_point_789.json'
-->filename='data_point_79.json'
-->filename='data_point_790.json'
-->filename='data_point_791.json'
-->filename='data_point_792.json'
-->filename='data_point_793.json'
-->filename='data_point_794.json'
-->filename='data_point_795.json'
-->filename='data_point_796.json'
-->filename='data_point_797.json'
-->filename='data_point_798.json'
-->filename='data_point_799.json'
-->filename='data_point_8.json'
-->filename='data_point_80.json'
-->filename='data_point_800.json'
-->filename='data_point_801.json'
-->filename='data_point_802.json'
-->filename='data_point_803.json'
-->filename='data_point_804.json'
-->filename='data_point_805.json'
-->filename='data_point_806.json'
-->filename='data_point_807.json'
-->filename='data_point_808.json'
-->filename='data_point_809.json'
-->filename='data_point_81.json'
-->filename='data_point_810.json'
-->filename='data_point_811.json'
-->filename='data_point_812.json'
-->filename='data_point_813.json'
-->filename='data_point_814.json'
-->filename='data_point_815.json'
-->filename='data_point_816.json'
-->filename='data_point_817.json'
-->filename='data_point_818.json'
-->filename='data_point_819.json'
-->filename='data_point_82.json'
-->filename='data_point_820.json'
-->filename='data_point_821.json'
-->filename='data_point_822.json'
-->filename='data_point_823.json'
-->filename='data_point_824.json'
-->filename='data_point_825.json'
-->filename='data_point_826.json'
-->filename='data_point_827.json'
-->filename='data_point_828.json'
-->filename='data_point_829.json'
-->filename='data_point_83.json'
-->filename='data_point_830.json'
-->filename='data_point_831.json'
-->filename='data_point_832.json'
-->filename='data_point_833.json'
-->filename='data_point_834.json'
-->filename='data_point_835.json'
-->filename='data_point_836.json'
-->filename='data_point_837.json'
-->filename='data_point_838.json'
-->filename='data_point_839.json'
-->filename='data_point_84.json'
-->filename='data_point_840.json'
-->filename='data_point_841.json'
-->filename='data_point_842.json'
-->filename='data_point_843.json'
-->filename='data_point_844.json'
-->filename='data_point_845.json'
-->filename='data_point_846.json'
-->filename='data_point_847.json'
-->filename='data_point_848.json'
-->filename='data_point_849.json'
-->filename='data_point_85.json'
-->filename='data_point_850.json'
-->filename='data_point_851.json'
-->filename='data_point_852.json'
-->filename='data_point_853.json'
-->filename='data_point_86.json'
-->filename='data_point_87.json'
-->filename='data_point_88.json'
-->filename='data_point_89.json'
-->filename='data_point_9.json'
-->filename='data_point_90.json'
-->filename='data_point_91.json'
-->filename='data_point_92.json'
-->filename='data_point_93.json'
-->filename='data_point_94.json'
-->filename='data_point_95.json'
-->filename='data_point_96.json'
-->filename='data_point_97.json'
-->filename='data_point_98.json'
-->filename='data_point_99.json'
854
```

note you might have to sort.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to extend the reply from @Mr_and_Mrs_D:

```py
import os
folder = 'C:/Dropbox'
file_count = sum(len(files) for _, _, files in os.walk(folder))
print(file_count)
```

This counts all the files in the folder and its subfolders. However, if you want to do some filtering - like only counting the files ending in `.svg`, you can do:

```py
import os
file_count = sum(len([f for f in files if f.endswith('.svg')]) for _, _, files in os.walk(folder))
print(file_count)
```

You basically replace:

- `len(files)`

with:

- `len([f for f in files if f.endswith('.svg')])`

Answer (score -2):

Convert it to a list, after that you can make use of the `len()` function:

```py
len(list(glob.glob('*')))
```