# Error while using listdir in Python

Tags: python, file, directory, listdir

I'm trying to get the list of files in a particular directory and count the number of files in the directory. I always get the following error:

```
WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '/client_side/*.*'
```

My code is:

```
print len([name for name in os.listdir('/client_side/') if os.path.isfile(name)])
```

I followed the code example given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632205/count-the-number-of-files-in-a-directory-using-python).

I am running the Python script on Pyscripter and the directory /client_side/ do exists. My python code is in the root folder and has a sub-folder called "client_side". Can someone help me out on this?

Comment: Just wondering if this has something to do with the '/' in windows ! Ideally, on windows, you should have something like `os.path.join('C:','client_side')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python raising FileNotFoundError for file name returned by os.listdir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28799353/python-raising-filenotfounderror-for-file-name-returned-by-os-listdir)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I decided to change the code into:

```
def numOfFiles(path):
    return len(next(os.walk(path))[2])
```

and use the following the call the code:

```
print numOfFiles("client_side")
```

Many thanks to everyone who told me how to pass the windows directory correctly in Python and to nrao91 in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632205/count-the-number-of-files-in-a-directory-using-python) for providing the function code.

Answer (score 14):

This error occurs when you use `os.listdir` on a *path* which does not refer to an existing path. 
For example:

```
>>> os.listdir('Some directory does not exist')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
WindowsError: [Error 3] : 'Some directory does not exist/*.*'
```

If you want to use `os.listdir`, you need to either guarantee the existence of the path that you would use, or use `os.path.exists` to check the existence first.

```
if os.path.exists('/client_side/'):
    do something
else:
    do something
```

Suppose your current working directory is `c:\foobar`, `os.listdir('/client_side/')` is equivalent to `os.listdir('c:/client_side')`, while `os.listdir('client_side/')` is equivalent to `os.listdir('c:/foobar/client_side')`. If your client_side directory is not in the root, such error will occur when using `os.listdir`.

For your 0 ouput problem, let us recall [`os.listdir(path)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html?highlight=listdir#os.listdir)

> Return a list containing the **names** of the entries in the directory given by path. The list is in arbitrary order. It does not include the special entries '.' and '..' even if they are present in the directory.

and [`os.path.isfile(path)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html?highlight=isfile#os.path.isfile).

> Return True if **path** is an existing regular file. This follows symbolic links, so both islink() and isfile() can be true for the same path.

`listdir` returns neither the absolute paths nor relative paths, but a list of the name of your files, while `isfile` requires path. Therefore, all of those names would yield `False`.

To obtain the path, we can either use [`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html?highlight=isfile#os.path.join) , concat two strings directly.

```
print ([name for name in os.listdir(path)
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, name))])
```

Or

```
print ([name for name in os.listdir('client_side/')
        if os.path.isfile('client_side/' + name)])
```

Comment: Hi. I don't have any windows error now but it always output the number of files as 0 although I have 7 files in the folder. Do you know why?

Comment: @Sakura: because `os.listdir` returns names. You should not use `os.path.isfile` on those names. I updated my post and gave a full explanation.

Comment: @Sakura You should really change the accepted answer

Comment: For OS operation in general, it would be nicer to do try except instead of if else as there might be other file operation happening at the same time. i.e. ```try:
 os.listdir('/client_side/')
except os.error:
 print("error listing directory")```

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1. os.listdir() does not do a glob pattern matching, use the [glob](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/glob.html) module for that
2. probably you do not have a directory called '/client_side/*.*', but maybe one
   without the *.* in the name

The syntax you used works fine, if the directory you look for exists, but there is no directory called '/client_side/*.*'.

In addition, be careful if using Python 2.x and os.listdir, as the results on windows are different when you use u'/client_side/' and just '/client_side'.

Comment: The glob is added by `posix.listdir`. In Win32 it uses [`FindFirstFileW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418) (or the ANSI version for bytes). It doesn't allow a trailing slash. So, instead of special casing root directories such as `C:\ `, Python just appends `*.*`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do just

```
os.listdir('client_side')
```

without slashes.

Comment: Hi. I don't have any windows error now but it always output the number of files as 0 although I have 7 files in the folder. Do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

As I can see a `WindowsError`, Just wondering if this has something to do with the '/' in windows ! Ideally, on windows, you should have something like `os.path.join('C:','client_side')`

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
print len([name for name in os.listdir('./client_side/') if os.path.isfile(name)])
```

with a "." before "/client_side/".

The dot means the current path where you are working (i.e. from where you are calling your code), so "./client_side/" represents the path you want, which is specified relatively to your current directory.

If you write only "/client_side/", in unix, the program would look for a folder in the root of the system, instead of the folder that you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to see all the files in the directory where your script is located, you can use `os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])`. This will give the path of the directory where your script is.

Then, with `fnmatch` function you can obtain the list of files in that directory with a name and/or extension specified in the `filename`variable.

```
import os,sys
from fnmatch import fnmatch

directory = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])    #this determines the directory
file_name= "*"                              #if you want the python files only, change "*" to "*.py"

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for name in files:
        if fnmatch(name, file_name):
            print (os.path.join(path, name))
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Checking for existence is subject to a race. Better to handle the error (beg forgiveness instead of ask permission). Plus, in Python 3 you can suppress errors. Use suppress from contextlib:

```
 with suppress(FileNotFoundError):
     for name in os.listdir('foo'):
         print(name)
```

Answer (score -1):

In case you might be using Pycharm or any type of IDE consider that you could be specifying wrong the working directory.

I hope you have a nice day.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).