# Python raising FileNotFoundError for file name returned by os.listdir

Tags: python, error-handling, file-not-found

I was trying to iterate over the files in a directory like this:

```
import os

path = r'E:/somedir'

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    f = open(filename, 'r')
    ... # process the file
```

But Python was throwing `FileNotFoundError` even though the file exists:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/ADMTM/TestT.py", line 6, in <module>
    f = open(filename, 'r')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'foo.txt'
```

So what is wrong here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is because [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) does not return the full path to the file, only the filename part; that is `'foo.txt'`, when open would want `'E:/somedir/foo.txt'` because the file does not exist in the current directory.

Use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to prepend the directory to your filename:

```
path = r'E:/somedir'

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    with open(os.path.join(path, filename)) as f:
        ... # process the file
```

(Also, you are not closing the file; the `with` block will take care of it automatically).

Answer (score 2):

[`os.listdir(directory)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) returns a list of file *names* in `directory`. So unless `directory` is your current working directory, you need to join those file names with the actual directory to get a proper absolute path:

```
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    filepath = os.path.join(path, filename)
    f = open(filepath,'r')
    raw = f.read()
    # ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative solution using [`pathlib.Path.iterdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.iterdir), which yields the full paths instead, removing the need to join paths:

```py
from pathlib import Path

path = Path(r'E:/somedir')

for filename in path.iterdir():
    with filename.open() as f:
        ... # process the file
```