# File can't be opened when using os.listdir(path)

Tags: python, windows, smtp, mime

```
for file in os.listdir(path):
try:
    with open(file, 'r') as fp:
        msg = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
        msg.set_payload(fp.read())
    encoders.encode_base64(msg)
    msg.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=os.path.basename(file))
    outer.attach(msg)
except:
    print("Unable to open one of the attachments. Error: ", sys.exc_info()[0])
    raise

composed = outer.as_string()
```

I get "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory" but the file exists! May be the os.listdir() object type?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python giving FileNotFoundError for file name returned by os.listdir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28799353/python-giving-filenotfounderror-for-file-name-returned-by-os-listdir)

Answer (score 0):

The `os.listdir` function returns only the filename. You should concat the path and the file name:

```
for file in os.listdir(path):
    try:
        with open(ps.path.join(path, file), 'r') as fp:
    ...
```