# subprocess.call with different values for args

Tags: python, loops, subprocess

I am kind of new to Python with a minimal background in basic programming so far. For bioinformatical analysis of datasets, I am trying to come up with a script automating most of it. The analysis includes running the multiple sequential markovian coalescent (MSMC) for inference of effective population history in Arabidopsis, a model organism for many studies.

The desired script would do the following:

1) iterate over input files ending in a specific ending, this is adressed with

```
for filename in os.listdir(input_directory):
   if filename.endswith(".multihetsep.txt")
```

and works so far.
2) then, the software for the analysis is callled on said files and this is where it gets tricky for me; for ONE case the subprocess.call would look like this:

```
call (["./msmc_1.1.0_linux64bit","-I0,1","-p1*2+15*1+1*2","- o",outdir+filename,filename])
```

with 
    outdir being assigned to a fixed string and filename obviously depending on the file that get's iterated over.

For the analysis, the script should be able to incorporate values from 0-27 in pairs of 2 and use them inside the call for the -I parameter and I am currently not seeing how I should do that. Also it should do the same in pairs of 4,6 and 8. The same problem, would in principle also apply to other parameters since I would have changing values for different runs of the analysis. Also, I'm struggling to find information on how to get the output files named in a stringent way. Let's say for -I 0,1, I would want to append _1 to the output filename (-o in this program specifies output location and prefix). The last arg "filename" provides the input files. Even after a lot of research (Google,stackoverflow,Python books), I was unable to find a solution for this issue.

Can I, in principle do this using the subprocess.call function or do I have to tackle this differently?

My current approach was to just simply run a shell script containing all of the desired scenarios but of course it's quite messy and contains lots of lines of code.

My entire code for now looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6
from subprocess import call
input_directory = "location of input files"
for filename in os.listdir(input_directory):
   if filename.endswith(".multihetsep.txt"):
        call (["./msmc_1.1.0_linux64bit","-I0,1","-p1*2+15*1+1*2","-o",outdir+filename,filename])
else:
    print("Specify valid input files.")
```

I would greatly appreciate any input and help I can possibly get on this.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: `listdir` results don't contain `input_directory`, so your code won't work as currently given. Also, you aren't asserting whether there's a directory separator after `outdir`.

Comment: Beyond that, the question is perhaps longer / more meandering than it needs to be. Ideally, you should be providing a [mcve] showing a *very specific* bug, with nothing unrelated to that bug (anything that already works you don't need to tell us about and shouldn't be included), and the exact text of the exception or error shown. If you were getting a no-such-file error on the input file, f/e, we'd know that it was because of the issue I mentioned in the comment above... but you aren't telling us what your specific error message is, so we can do nothing but guess.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28799353/python-giving-filenotfounderror-for-file-name-returned-by-os-listdir as an example of a related question (opening the filename received from `os.listdir()` in Python rather than passing it to a subprocess, but encountered due to the same underlying error/issue nonetheless).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The issue is not that the code is not running, for now it is doing what it is supposed to (I edited out the value of input_directory for privacy reasons). The issue I am having is that I would like to pass changing values for the -I parameter (and others) in the software I call through subprocess.call, if possible. Also I would like to rewrite my code so that the output contains filename with an added unique identifier (for example behind it) so I can batch run this code. Hope this helps in clarifying my issue a bit.

Comment: ...so, what's the specific language-level problem encountered in the course of making that change? Focus the question around that problem. If it's just a question of knowing how to append to strings, `'-I0-1_%s' % (something,)` f/e will do the trick... but a question about how to append to strings doesn't even need to include anything about subprocess.call(), or `os.listdir()`, or other conflating factors *at all*. The "minimal" part of the MCVE definition is relevant -- focusing the question on what you're having trouble doing will stop folks from getting sidetracked with unrelated details.

Comment: The problem is that I am either unable to understand the solutions I have looked up so far or that I don't know how to approach my issue on a "programming" level since I am quite new to python itself. My approaches so far have been to just define a list and try to slice over items in the list in pairs of 2 for a start but this produces a TypeError (TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list) when using call (["./msmc_1.1.0_linux64bit","-I",hap_mad[0:1],"-p1*2+15*1+1*2","-o",outdir+filename,filename]).

Comment: Thanks for the input so far, I will try fiddling with the code some more. Also thank you for the input on how to "format" my question better. I will try sticking to it for further issues.