# delete all the files from a directory where filename starts with 'df'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to delete all the files from a directory where filename starts with 'df'. I used to below code to do the same but I am getting the below error saying `No such file or directory: 'df2.csv'`although print statement does show df2.csv

```
filelist = [ f for f in os.listdir("/a/b/") if f.startswith("df") ]
for f in filelist:
    print(f)
    os.remove(f)


df2.csv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'df2.csv'
```

Comment: `f` is just a filename, not a path. The file you want to delete is at `os.path.join('/a/b', f)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Python giving FileNotFoundError for file name returned by os.listdir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28799353/python-giving-filenotfounderror-for-file-name-returned-by-os-listdir)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

It is because you are just adding the filename and its extension into the list `filelist`.

In this particular case, `os.remove()` requires you pass it an absolute path since the file path is not relative to the script path.

You need to update your `filelist` list comprehension to the following for it to work:

`root = r'path to your directory'`

`filelist = [ os.path.join(root, f) for f in os.listdir(root) if f.startswith("df") ]`

`os.path.join(root, f)` will join the root path and the filename.ext creating an absolute path.

Comment: `os.remove` does not require an absolute path. A relative path would work, as long as it was correct.