# Zipping files in multiple directories / FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, gzip

I have a folder structure where I have my root folder and then 3 other folders in the root folder.

```
Root_folder
|
|- Folder1
   |- file1.txt
   |- file2.txt
|- Folder2
   |- file3.txt
   |- file4.jpg
|- Folder3
   |- file5.txt
```

I'm trying to get my script to run through each of the three folders and calculate the age of the files in each folder. This works fine, however I'm having an issue with my zip function.

I get an error saying there's no such file or directory. If I add a `print(file)` before I call  `zip_file` I will get an output of  `file4.jpg`

```
import os 
import time
import gzip

root_directory = ('C:/Users/Path/Desktop/To_Files/')

folders = ['inbox', 'outbox']

retention_age_days = {
    '.txt':100,
    '.jpg':200,
    }

zip_extension = ('.jpg') 

files_to_zip = []

def zip_file():

    for file in files_to_zip:
        fp = open(file, "rb")
        data = fp.read()
        bindata = bytearray(data)
        with gzip.open(file + ".gz", "wb") as f:
            f.write(bindata)
        return


for folder in folders:
    os.path.join(str((root_directory, folder)))
    files = [f for f in os.listdir(folder) if f.endswith(tuple(retention_age_days.keys()))]

    for file in files:
        time_created = os.stat(folder).st_ctime
        now = time.time()
        file_age_seconds = now - time_created # file age in seconds
        file_age_days = (now - time_created) / 86400 # 1 day = 86400 seconds
        ending = "." + file.split(".")[-1]
        if ending in retention_age_days:
            # deletion statments should go in here, replacing print statements
            if file_age_days > retention_age_days[ending]:
                print(file, file_age_days, "file is older than retention days")
            elif file_age_days <= retention_age_days[ending] and file.endswith(zip_extension):
                files_to_zip.append(file)
                zip_file()
            elif file_age_days <= retention_age_days[ending]:
                print(file, file_age_days, "file is not older than retention days")
```

I'm not sure what's going on. When I  `print(os.getcwd())` even in the  `for folder in folders` loop I keep getting an output saying my cwd is (C:/Users/Path/Desktop/To_Files/') ```

Any help to fix my zip function would be much appreciated!

EDIT: Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Path/Desktop/To_Files/file.py", line 50, in <module>
    zip_file()
  File "C:/Users/Path/Desktop/To_Files/file.py", line 24, in zip_file
    fp = open(file, "rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'jpg_test.jpg'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python giving FileNotFoundError for file name returned by os.listdir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28799353/python-giving-filenotfounderror-for-file-name-returned-by-os-listdir)

Comment: That's iterating over files in one directory. I want to iterate over multiple files in multiple directories.

Comment: if you want join path then assign result to variable and don't use `str()` because you create wrong path `fullpath = os.path.join(root_directory, folder)`

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: with this error I can only say: to read file in different folder you have to create full path - `fullpath = os.path.join(root_directory, folder)` and then `open(fullpath)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.listdir()` gives only filenames in folder but to open file you need full path - `folder/filename` so you have to use `os.path.join(folder, f)` in

```
 extensions = tuple(retention_age_days.keys())
 files = [os.path.join(folder, f) 
            for f in os.listdir(folder) 
               if f.endswith(extensions)]
```

---

BTW: in next loop you get again and again `stat()` for `folder`

```
 time_created = os.stat(folder).st_ctime
```

maybe you means `file` instead `folder`

```
 time_created = os.stat(file).st_ctime
```

---

In `zip_file()` if you use `return` inside `for`-loop then it exits after first file. You could skip `return`. But you could send list as argument `def zip_file(files_to_zip):`