# Getting FileNotFoundError: when I try to read the excel files in my directory

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to print all the excel files in my `Cleaned_Data` folder but when I run the code I get:

```
FileNotFoundError
```

The code:

```py
directory = r"C:\Users\andre\OneDrive\Desktop\python_web_scrapper\Cleaned_Data"
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".xlsx"):
        pd.read_excel(filename)
```

Comment: You want to open a file in `C:\Users\andre\OneDrive\Desktop\python_web_scrapper\Cleaned_Data` but you tell your code to open a file in the current working directory.

Comment: filename does not contains directory name you must add directory path

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python giving FileNotFoundError for file name returned by os.listdir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28799353/python-giving-filenotfounderror-for-file-name-returned-by-os-listdir)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filename` only contains the name of the file and not its entire path. Your script does not see the file since it's looking for it where you are and not in the `directory` folder. You need to add the path to the file:

```py
import os

directory = r"C:\Users\andre\OneDrive\Desktop\python_web_scrapper\Cleaned_Data"
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".xlsx"):
        pd.read_excel(os.path.join(directory, filename))
```