# Python saying "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'script.vbs'" in for loop that is looping through the directory the file is in

Tags: python

Python is giving me the error `"FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'script.vbs'"` but the file is in the same directory that it's looping through.

Script:

```
import os
path = r"C:\Users\bruh\Downloads\Directory"

directory = os.listdir(path)
for file in directory:
    print(file)
    open(file)
```

By the way, it literally prints the file name and then says it cant find it.

Comment: `open` opens relative to the current working directory, not relative to `path`.

Comment: This has already been asked & answered here: [Python giving FileNotFoundError for file name returned by os.listdir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28799353/python-giving-filenotfounderror-for-file-name-returned-by-os-listdir)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It prints the file name, but not the path.  You need to add the path:

```
    fobj = open( os.path.join( path, file ) )
```

Comment: nevermind it gives no errors but doesn't open the file now

Comment: Yes, it does open the file, but you have to store the file object in a variable if you're going to read from it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
path = r"C:\Users\bruh\Downloads\Directory"
# check current working dir
cwd = os.getcwd()
print(cwd)
# change you os dir to path
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\bruh\Downloads\Directory')
for i in os.listdir():
    print(i, end='\n')
    open(i)
```