# WinError 2, python cant find my file when os.remove

Tags: python

printing the name of the files goes fine but when I try to use os.remove it says it cannot find the file. I also tried full path but also didnt work.

here is my code

```
 import os
 for tempfiles in os.listdir(r"All Posts"):
 os.remove(tempfiles)
```

Comment: `os.remove(os.path.join("All Posts", tempfiles))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python giving FileNotFoundError for file name returned by os.listdir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28799353/python-giving-filenotfounderror-for-file-name-returned-by-os-listdir)

Comment: `os.listdir()` returns *only the filenames*.  Anything you do with those bare filenames is going to look for them in the current working directory, NOT whatever directory you passed to `listdir()`.  You have to combine the directory and filename into a full pathname - using `os.path.join()`, typically.