# PDF not found and hence cannot be merged

Tags: python, pypdf

My code is as follows:

```py
from pypdf import PdfWriter
import os 

files = [file for file in os.listdir("D:/Python/Programs_made/PDF_Merger") if file.endswith(".pdf")]

merger = PdfWriter()

for pdf in files:
    merger.append(pdf)

merger.write("merged-pdf.pdf")
merger.close()
```

The error is:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'PDF-1.pdf'
```

The file exists(Please explain if path is wrong)

Every file is stored inside of folder PDF_Merger(i.e .py file and all PDF's)

I think everrthing is perfect but getting error that file does not exist at that location so not getting a merged PDF file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python raising FileNotFoundError for file name returned by os.listdir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28799353/python-raising-filenotfounderror-for-file-name-returned-by-os-listdir)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.listdir` returns the name of the files WITHOUT the directory name so you have to append the directory name to the filename as shown below

```
folder_name = "D:/Python/Programs_made/PDF_Merger"
files = [file for file in os.listdir(folder_name) if file.endswith(".pdf")]

merger = PdfWriter()

for pdf in files:
    merger.append(folder_name+"/"+pdf)
```