# Why does os.path.isfile return False?

Tags: python

```
>>> import os
>>> os.listdir("/home/user/Desktop/1")
['1.txt', '2', '3.txt']
>>> os.path.isfile("/home/user/Desktop/1/1.txt")
True
>>> for i in os.listdir("/home/user/Desktop/1"):
...     print(os.path.isfile(i))
...
False
False
False
>>>
```

Two of them are files, why is the output `False` when it should be `True`?

Answer (score 54):

When you print `os.path.isfile(i)`, you're checking if "1.txt" or "2" or "3.txt" is a file, whereas when you run `os.path.isfile("/home/user/Desktop/1/1.txt")` you have a full path to the file.

Try replacing that line with

```
print(os.path.isfile("/home/user/desktop/1/" + i))
```

**Edit:**

As mentioned in the comment below by icktoofay, a better solution might be to replace the line with

```
print(os.path.isfile(os.path.join("/home/user/desktop/1", i)))
```

or to earlier store "/home/user/desktop/1" to some variable x, allowing the line to be replaced with

```
print(os.path.isfile(os.path.join(x,i)))
```

Comment: If the directory name and file name were in variables, `os.path.join` would let you avoid hard-coding a `/` between them.

Answer (score 11):

The problem is with your CWD (Current Working Directory) because `os.listdir()` give you files whose are relative to the provided path and it's inconsistent with CWD. The solution is to set your CWD before using `os.listidr()`:

```
dir_to_delete = '/home/user/Desktop/1'

os.chdir(dir_to_delete)

[f for f in os.listdir() if os.path.isfile(f)]
```

or just repair path to files:

```
[f for f in os.listdir(dir_to_delete) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir_to_delete, f))]
```