# python starts ok from terminal but not as cron at boot

Tags: python, ubuntu, cron

I have a python script. I'm able to start it fine from the terminal (ubuntu) but when I set it as a cron job it starts, but does not function the same.  I think there is a problem with a path.  Is there a way for me to set a script to start up as if I was starting it from the terminal? I've tried various ways to fix this and tons of googling.

Not sure if these details are relevant... but this script searches it's own directory for images and then dumps that into a dictionary type variable.  I used os.path. It works fine from the terminal but when I set it as a start up it never works.

Comment: You can print current os.path, to see if this is the problem, or something else. My cron calls usually starts with /usr/bin/python <script>, and not calling it directly. Additionally, if you use virtualenv, you need to start it from "that python", not default one.

Comment: I think I might create a much more basic script using os.path that just creates a log of all the files within it's own directory and see what it does on boot.

Answer (score 0):

I usually avoid this type of problem by making sure I'm very explicit about my current path

```
import os
THIS_DIRECTORY      = os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

This way THIS_DIRECTORY is guaranteed to be the directory that the python script is in, rather than the directory it is being run from, which is what os.curdir will report.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was os.path.isfile(name)
To fix the problem I now have this unwieldier line, sigh.

```
for i in range(len([name for name in os.listdir('/home/dude/Pictures/Wall/') if os.path.isfile('/home/dude/Pictures/Wall/'+name)])):
```

found my answer here ... [Why do os.path.isfile return False?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893542/why-do-os-path-isfile-return-false)