# http.server if statement os.path.isfile() doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

So this is my code:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import requests, json, os

PORT = 1337

class getHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def handleJSON(self, provider, data):
        if provider == "provider_1":
            json_data = json.loads(data)
            sl_token = json_data["access_token"]
            return sl_token
        elif provider == "provider_2":
            json_data = json.loads(data)
            pb_token = json_data["access_token"]
            return pb_token

    def do_GET(self):
        data = self.requestline

        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type','text/html')
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(b'You may close the tab now')

        print("Raw Data: " + data)

        if not os.path.isfile("PbToken.txt") and os.path.isfile("SlToken.txt"):
            if "GET /?code=" and "&state=" in data: # Provider_1
                print("Provider_1 Data:", data)
                pb_code = data[data.find("/?code=") + len("/?code="):data.find("&state=")]

                with open("PbToken.txt", "w") as file:
                    file.write(pb_code)
                    file.close()

            elif "GET /?code=" in data: # Provider_2
                print("Provider_2 Data:", data)
                sl_code = data.strip()
                sl_code = sl_code[sl_code.rindex("/?code=") + len("/?code="):sl_code.rindex(" ")]

                with open("SlToken.txt", "w") as file:
                    file.write(sl_code)
                    file.close()

        else:
            raise SystemExit

server = HTTPServer(('localhost', PORT), getHandler)
print("Started server on port", PORT)

server.serve_forever()
```

So from the class `getHandler` in the function `do_GET(self)` it never makes it past the `if not os.path.isfile("PbToken.txt") and os.path.isfile("SlToken.txt"):` statement (I've of course made sure the files aren't actually there). I want it to check if both of the files exist, if they don't do what's written below. If the files exist they should go straight to the `else` statement where it uses `raise SystemExit`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're negating only the first condition (`os.path.isfile("PbToken.txt")`), and not the second one (`os.path.isfile("SlToken.txt")`), so you're effectively checking if `PbToken.txt` doesn't exist and `SlToken.txt` exists.

Comment: Aren't you missing a `not`: `and os.path.isfile("SlToken.txt"):`?

Comment: Zwer suggetsion is True. I think this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893542/why-do-os-path-isfile-return-false, so try to replace your condition with print(os.path.isfile("Path_file" + i))

Comment: Are you sure you're in the correct folder? Add `print(os.getcwd())` before that line and see if you're in the right place

Comment: I checked (`os.getcwd`) and I am indeed in the right folder. The reason why I only have `not` for the first one is because `True and False` & `False and True` both return `False`. So it would give the same thing anyway.

Comment: Atleast that's what I get when I type it in console. I just tried adding `not` to both. It did everything it needed to and printed it the first time. The second time it only printed `Raw Data: #some data here` and skipped the `if` statement again even though the file was never made.

Comment: Just edited the question, should probably have included the part where the files are actually made.

Answer (score 0):

It should've been `or` not `and`...

So simply `if not os.path.isfile("PbToken.txt") or not os.path.isfile("SlToken.txt"):` to see if one of the files are missing.