# Python: os.path.isfile does't detect the file

Tags: python, windows, file-io, operating-system

I've got a script that updates a file hierarchy by checking if each needed file exists and if not downloads them.

Because using full paths was causing issues to what I believed were filenames that were too long and often contain special characters I've changed it to `os.chdir` into each subdirectory, check for the required files and download them.

However my program is consistently crashing on one file because `os.path.isfile` for some reason says it does not exist (even though it does). The really confusing part is when it tries to download it with `with open(path, "wb") as f:` and runs into a `FileNotFoundError` even though it's opening in write mode.

It appears that you can get `FileNotFoundError` when you try `open` if the path links to a directory that doesn't exist but in my case it doesn't link to any directories.

I've tried using `os.path.split` on the filename in case it somehow contains a slash or backslash however the filename seems fine.

Here is the code. This issue isn't on the first directory it runs into, it manages to work through at least a dozen before it runs into this.

```
stepOut = 1
paths = list(map(unquote, url.split("/")[6:]))
for index, path in enumerate(paths):
    if index != len(paths) - 1:
        if not os.path.isdir(path):
            os.mkdir(path)
        os.chdir(path)
        stepOut += 1
    else:
        if not os.path.isfile(path):
            r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
            if r.status_code == 200:
                print("Saving", path)
                with open(path, 'wb') as f:
                    r.raw.decode_content = True
                    shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
            else:
                print("Error getting:", url)
        else:
            print("Skipping", paths)
os.chdir("..\\" * stepOut)
```

Comment: Can you post the code if possible?

Comment: Another trick I tried to fix this was to download the file as "temp" and then rename it to the correct name but I still run into the exact same issue.

Comment: Just checked if it was somehow the filename being too long but its 91 characters long and the script manages files over 110 characters long before it runs into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was my original suspicion all along and the filename was in fact too long.

The base file name wasn't the longest but the full path to the filename including every subdirectory to root was too long.

The issue was fixed by moving the entire project to the root directory.

An interesting take away from this is you can create file structures that have filenames that are too long in window explorer but if you even try to simply detect if there are files there with python, you'll run into issues.

Comment: In Python 3.6+ running on Windows 10 with long paths enabled, we can use paths with up to about 32760 characters without any extra processing. Otherwise, for older versions of Python or Windows that lack implicit long-path support, we have to prefix the fully-qualified path with `"\\\\?\\"`. If it's a UNC path (e.g. `"\\\\server\\share\\file"`), rewrite it to use the "UNC" device (e.g. `"\\\\?\\UNC\server\share\file"`). Also, for Python 2, we have to use a `unicode` string.

Comment: I think your original suspicion is wrong on this one.  I think it would be more related to this just FYI: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893542/why-does-os-path-isfile-return-false