# os.path.isfile() return False

Tags: python, python-os

why this code return nothing?

```
>>> [f for f in os.listdir('Scripts') if os.path.isfile(os.path.abspath(f))]
[]
>>> os.listdir('Scripts')
['dmypy.exe', 'easy_install-3.8.exe', 'easy_install.exe', 'f2py.exe', 'futurize.exe', 'iptest.exe', 'iptest3.exe', 'ipython.exe', 'ipython3.exe', 'mypy.exe', 'mypyc', 'pasteurize.exe', 'pip.exe', 'pip3.8.exe', 'pip3.exe', 'prichunkpng', 'priforgepng', 'prigreypng', 'pripalpng', 'pripamtopng', 'pripnglsch', 'pripngtopam', 'priweavepng', 'pygmentize.exe', 'pyi-archive_viewer.exe', 'pyi-bindepend.exe', 'pyi-grab_version.exe', 'pyi-makespec.exe', 'pyi-set_version.exe', 'pyinstaller.exe', 'stubgen.exe', 'stubtest.exe', 'wheel.exe']
```

I understand the answer from this question [Why do os.path.isfile return False?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17893542/13387384), but here I've added a full path to the filename, but anyway it is don't working

Comment: Its because `os.path.abspath()` only adds the current dir onto each filename and not `'Scripts'` as well.

Comment: Thanks, I missed this feature. This is the answer to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code returns an empty `list` because `os.path.abspath()` simply appends the given filename onto the current directory and none of those files are actually present in the current directory.

If you want to get all the files from the `Scripts` folder then you need to go with the answer from @Roy2012

Answer (score 3):

`abspath` isn't the right tool here. Use `os.join` with the "Scripts" directory instead:

```
[f for f in os.listdir('Scripts') if os.path.isfile(os.path.join("Scripts", f))]
```

With regards to `abspath` - according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath), it basically joins the current working directory to the filename. This is not what you want if the files you're looking into aren't in the current directory.

Quoting the documentation:

`abspath`: ... On most platforms, this is equivalent to calling the function `normpath()` as follows: `normpath(join(os.getcwd(), path))`.

Comment: I know, I just want to understand the logic of python :)

Comment: @salius - if this answers your question, do you mind accepting it as an answer for future generations?

Comment: I wrote it to @quamrana comment, I think, his comment was more precise exactly for such a question. I can't accept the comment as an answer, only other users may do it