# Count the number of files in a directory using JavaScript/nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I count the number of files in a directory using `nodejs` with just plain JavaScript or packages? I want to do something like this:

[How to count the number of files in a directory using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632205/count-the-number-of-files-in-a-directory-using-python)

Or in bash script I'd do this:

```
getLength() {
  DIRLENGTH=1
  until [ ! -d "DIR-$((DIRLENGTH+1))"  ]; do
    DIRLENGTH=$((DIRLENGTH+1))
  done
}
```

Comment: What you tried so far?

Comment: It's definitely possible. Do you have a particular issue / question about it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting all filenames in a directory with node.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727167/getting-all-filenames-in-a-directory-with-node-js)

Comment: Possible duplicate comments are generated as part of the review process. They're often helpful to figure readers regardless of the decision at the time because they populate the related questions list.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Using [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html), I found retrieving the directory file count to be straightforward.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const dir = './directory';

fs.readdir(dir, (err, files) => {
  console.log(files.length);
});
```

For the TS enthusiasts:

```js
fs.readdir(dir, (err: NodeJS.ErrnoException | null, files: string[]) => {
  console.log(files.length);
});
```

Comment: I had implemented the above, It shown that above syntax was wrong. And I had replaced the => to function()..After Executed above, I had faced that "files.length" of undefined

Comment: Maybe you're in an environment which does not support the fat arrow syntax introduced in ES6. I can assure you that the syntax is correct and there is some mistake on your end.

Comment: does it count subdirectories?

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira Yes, it counts directories (except the '.' and '..'), pipes, FIFO, block devices etc. [See all the stuff if counts](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#class-fsdirent). You have to filter the output, usually.

Comment: This is nice and clean but memory usage is `O(n)`, whereas it seems like it should be possible to implement an ideal solution in `O(1)` (I'm not, however, sure how to interface with the filesystem in order to achieve this! :P)

Comment: Once writing TS code, the strict typing should be used for the sake of a cleaner code. I mean 'err' and 'files' variables

Comment: but this won't count files in nested folders

Comment: @Matteo OP never specified this as a requirement.

Answer (score 23):

```
const fs = require('fs')
const length = fs.readdirSync('/home/directory').length
```

Answer (score 4):

1) Download shell.js and node.js (if you don't have it)
2) Go where you download it and create there a file named `countFiles.js`

```
var sh = require('shelljs');

var count = 0;
function annotateFolder (folderPath) {
  sh.cd(folderPath);
  var files = sh.ls() || [];

  for (var i=0; i<files.length; i++) {
    var file = files[i];

    if (!file.match(/.*\..*/)) {
      annotateFolder(file);
      sh.cd('../');
    } else {
      count++;
    }
  }
}
if (process.argv.slice(2)[0])
  annotateFolder(process.argv.slice(2)[0]);
else {
  console.log('There is no folder');
}

console.log(count);
```

3) Open the command promt in the shelljs folder (where countFiles.js is) and write `node countFiles "DESTINATION_FOLDER"` (e.g. `node countFiles "C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\testFolder"`)

Answer (score 3):

Alternative solution without external module, maybe not the most efficient code, but will do the trick without external dependency:

```
var fs = require('fs');

function sortDirectory(path, files, callback, i, dir) {
    if (!i) {i = 0;}                                            //Init
    if (!dir) {dir = [];}
    if(i < files.length) {                                      //For all files
        fs.lstat(path + '\\' + files[i], function (err, stat) { //Get stats of the file
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            if(stat.isDirectory()) {                            //Check if directory
                dir.push(files[i]);                             //If so, ad it to the list
            }
            sortDirectory(callback, i + 1, dir);                //Iterate
        });
    } else {
        callback(dir);                                          //Once all files have been tested, return
    }
}

function listDirectory(path, callback) {
    fs.readdir(path, function (err, files) {                    //List all files in the target directory
        if(err) {
            callback(err);                                      //Abort if error
        } else {
            sortDirectory(path, files, function (dir) {         //Get only directory
                callback(dir);
            });
        }
    })
}

listDirectory('C:\\My\\Test\\Directory', function (dir) {
    console.log('There is ' + dir.length + ' directories: ' + dir);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think many people look for function like this:

```
const countFiles = (dir: string): number =>
  fs.readdirSync(dir).reduce((acc: number, file: string) => {
    const fileDir = `${dir}/${file}`;

    if (fs.lstatSync(fileDir).isDirectory()) {
      return (acc += countFiles(fileDir));
    }

    if (fs.lstatSync(fileDir).isFile()) {
      return ++acc;
    }

    return acc;
  }, 0);
```

They count all files in the entire file tree.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got a bash script like approach for this:

```
const shell = require('shelljs')
const path = require('path')

module.exports.count = () => shell.exec(`cd ${path.join('path', 'to', 'folder')} || exit; ls -d -- */ | grep 'page-*' | wc -l`, { silent:true }).output
```

That's it.

Comment: Hey, this works. It's an artifact of a bash thinker I admit, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

Here the simple code,

```
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';
RNFS.readDir(dirPath)
    .then((result) => {
     console.log(result.length);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const readdir = (path) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readdir(path, (error, files) => {
      error ? reject(error) : resolve(files);
    });
  });
};s

readdir("---path to directory---").then((files) => {
  console.log(files.length);
});
```

Comment: Adding some description with code helps better understand the solution to user.