# How to get files contained in a path

Tags: javascript

In the following path:

```
app/test/vehicle/
```

there are several .js file. Is there any way in Javascript where I can get the number of .js file contains in the above-mentioned path?

I am using webStorm environment

Comment: Are you using node?

Comment: In the browser? no. With node? yes.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback

Comment: @Li357 sorry I am absolutely new to javascript..but I am not using a webbrowser..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count the number of files in a directory using JavaScript/nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33775113/count-the-number-of-files-in-a-directory-using-javascript-nodejs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using node:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const dir = './directory';

fs.readdir(dir, (err, files) => {
  console.log(files.length);
});
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43747896/3650835

Comment: Instead of copying the code, flag as a duplicate. The same answer doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Since javascript doesn't have local filesystem access when run in the browser, there is no way to access local files from javascript. If you are asking about accessing all files hosted on a cdn or something similar in that directory, there is still no way to tell which requests will return a 20x.

If you are using nodejs, use the [`fs.readdir`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback) function:

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readdir('app/test/vehicle/', (err, files) => {
  files.forEach(file => { console.log(file);} );
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to access the file system from a web page.

If you are using nodejs, then you can use `fs.readdir` or `fs.readdirSync`:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const dir = './directory';

fs.readdir(dir, (err, files) => {
   console.log(files.filter(file => file.endsWith(".js")).length);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you trying to get list of the files? On the client side it is impossible. JavaScript does not have access to the client file system. If you are trying to do it in the server side using for example node.js then you can do something like:

```
var filesys = require('fs');
var files = filesys.readdirSync('/app/test/vehicle/');
```