# Count the number of files in a directory in a relative path python

Tags: python, file, operating-system

I am trying to count the number of files in a directory. This program counts the number of photos of a person. The person's name is used as the file's name.

[image]

Here is the full file path

```
C:\Users\barry\PycharmProjects\face_rec\images\Barry
```

I have looked at [How to count the number of files in a directory using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632205/how-to-count-the-number-of-files-in-a-directory-using-python) and came up with this solution:

```
numberOfFile=(len([filename for filename in os.listdir('images/'+name.get()) if os.path.isfile('images/'+name.get())]))
print(numberOfFile)
```

However this solution always returns `0`

I would like to avoid using the absolute path, but if the only option is using the absolute path, that is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't making use of the `filename` variable with which you iterate through the list returned by `os.listdir`. You can use `os.path.join` to join the directory name with it so that it can be found by `os.path.isfile`:

```
numberOfFile = len([filename for filename in os.listdir('images/' + name.get())
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join('images/' + name.get(), filename))])
```