# Batch rename .txt files with first line of text - MacOS

Tags: macos, file, terminal, batch-rename

I have 8k+ text files that I would like to rename with the first line of text of the respective file. Most lines are up to three words but some are more complex, with commas and other punctuation, e.g. "My Milk(also known as Annie Ps 'Tell The Milk' ".

I have used this:

```
for i in *.txt; do mv "$i" "$(head -1 "$i")".txt; done
```

Only issue I am having is files getting overwritten. I guess I will have to append a sequence to mitigate this.

Comment: You can write a python script that iterates through the whole directory, open each file (in read mode), save the first line in a variable, close the file, rename the file and repeat.

Comment: Check this for counting the files: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2632205/11024053

Comment: Thanks but I am more of a copy paster, that page just confused me more.