# how to get no files of each folder in a directory with corresponding file name

Tags: python, dataset, data-science

In my dataset i have folders as follows :
`['c7', 'c1', 'c4', 'c0', 'c6', 'c9', 'c8', 'c2', 'c5', 'c3']` 

i have found length of each folder using:

`for i in os.listdir('../Project/Dataset/imgs/train'):`

 `print(len(os.listdir('../Project/Dataset/imgs/train/'+i)))`

I need to display each folder size with corresponding folder name

Ex: c7 : 2000
c3 : 2000

Comment: [os.path.getsize](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getsize)

Comment: this thread should probably help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632205/how-to-count-the-number-of-files-in-a-directory-using-python

Answer (score 1):

If it is just about printing, then you can do the following:

```
import os
for i in os.listdir('../Project/Dataset/imgs/train'):
    num_files = len(os.listdir('../Project/Dataset/imgs/train/'+i))
    print("{} : {}".format(i, num_files))
```