# What is the difference between pathlib glob('*') and iterdir?

Tags: python, pathlib

Suppose I'm writing code using `pathlib` and I want to iter over all the files in the same level of a directory.

I can do this in two ways:

```py
p = pathlib.Path('/some/path')
for f in p.iterdir():
    print(f)
```

```py
p = pathlib.Path('/some/path')
for f in p.glob('*'):
    print(f)
```

Is one of the options better in any way?

Comment: It's easy to find difference if you will look in docs of [`glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) and [`iterdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.iterdir). Use one which fits your requirements better.

Comment: I know that, but using `glob('*')` like this will result the same output as `iterdir()` I was wondering whether one of them is better for this use case

Comment: Why put the API to extra work parsing and testing against a filter pattern when you could just... not?

Comment: Well, @ShadowRanger that might be the answer I was looking for.. :)

Comment: This is a valid question. Generally it's a sign of bad design if an interface is more complex than necessary. If it's about performance, `glob('*')` could be implemented as a special case, or `glob()` without arguments could iterate over all files.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Expansion of [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63001429/what-is-the-difference-between-pathlib-glob-and-iterdir#comment111411303_63001429): Why put the API to extra work parsing and testing against a filter pattern when you could just... not?

`glob` is better when you need to make use of the filtering feature and the filter is simple and string-based, as it simplifies the work. Sure, hand-writing simple matches (filtering `iterdir` via `if path.endswith('.txt'):` instead of  `glob('*.txt')`) might be more efficient than the regex based pattern matching `glob` hides, but it's generally not worth the trouble of reinventing the wheel given that disk I/O is orders of magnitude slower.

But if you don't need the filtering functionality at all, don't use it. `glob` is gaining you nothing in terms of code simplicity or functionality, and hurting performance, so just use `iterdir`.

Comment: and when iterating over files recursively?

Comment: @UlfGjerdingen: `Path.glob` (with explicit `**/`) or `Path.rglob` (which adds implicit `**/` prefix) work. At that point, `glob` is doing actual work for you. Or you can use `os.walk` and convert to `Path`s as you go. Up to you.

Answer (score 14):

In addition to the excellent [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63003211), there's at least one difference in behavior:

If the directory doesn't exist, `iterdir()` raises a `FileNotFoundError`. `glob('*')` treats this case like an empty folder, returning an empty iterable.

```
>>> import pathlib
>>> path = pathlib.Path('/some/path')
>>> list(path.glob('*'))
[]
>>> list(path.iterdir())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [...]
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/some/path'
```