# How can I find the number of files within a directory?

Tags: python, file, count, directory, pathlib

How can I get the number of files in a certain folder using pathlib ?

```
from pathlib import Path
fileDir = Path("C:/Users/Jonas/Desktop/Test")
```

Comment: Probably a duplicate. This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632205/how-to-count-the-number-of-files-in-a-directory-using-python

Comment: Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) or [`.rglob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rglob):

```
from pathlib import Path
fileDir = Path("C:/Users/Jonas/Desktop/Test")
excelFiles = fileDir.rglob('*.xl*')
print(len(list(excelFiles)))
>>> 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```py
import os
import glob
files = 0
folder_path = 'your path'
    for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path, '*.xls')): # .xls for example
        files += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little function I put together that will list all the files in a given folder. You can then use the length of the list to see how many there are, or loop though the list if you want to do anything with them:

```py
import os

def list_files(folder, extensions=None):
    file_list = []
    all_files = os.listdir(folder)
    for name in all_files:
        if extensions is not None:
            for ext in extensions:
                if name.endswith(ext):
                    file_list.append(f'{folder}{os.sep}{name}')
        else:
            file_list.append(f'{folder}{os.sep}{name}')
    return file_list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    all_files = list_files('C:/Users/Jonas/Desktop/Test')
    print('total files: ')
    print(len(all_files))

    all_excel_files = list_files('C:/Users/Jonas/Desktop/Test', ['xlsx', 'xls', 'xlsm'])
    print('excel files:')
    print(len(all_excel_files))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the number of all files, you could do something like this:

```py
from pathlib import Path
fileDir = Path("C:/Users/Jonas/Desktop/Test")

print(len[f for f in fileDir.iterdir()])
```

If you need to filter on the name, you can add a condition on `f.name` or use `fileDir.glob()` or `fileDir.rglob()`, like the others suggested. E.g,

```py
from pathlib import Path
fileDir = Path("C:/Users/Jonas/Desktop/Test")

print(len[f for f in fileDir.iterdir() if len(f.name) < 10])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import os
os.system('ls /etc | wc -l')
```

https://devconnected.com/how-to-count-files-in-directory-on-linux/

Comment: OP is probably looking for a python command to solve the problem :)